Matching closed form BER with integrals for QPSK modulation
I am trying numerically compute the $\bar{P}_b$ for QPSK in a Rayleigh fading channel according to the formula,
$$
\bar{P}_b = \int_0^\infty P_b(\gamma)p_{\gamma_s}(\gamma)\ d\gamma 
$$
for QPSK $P_b(\gamma)= Q(\sqrt{2\gamma})$ and since it is a Rayleigh fading channel $p_{\gamma_s}(\gamma) = (1 /\gamma_s)\exp(- \gamma /\gamma_s)$.
For the closed form $\bar{P}_b$ according to this paper, it should be,
$$
\bar{P}_b = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma + 1}} \right)
$$
However, when plotting the lines does not line up,

My python code is a follows,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

erfc = np.vectorize(math.erfc)
Q = np.vectorize(lambda x: 0.5*erfc(x/np.sqrt(2)))
Q_qpsk = lambda s: Q(np.sqrt(2 * s))

def qpsk_integrate(snr):
    gamma = np.arange(0, 10000)
    P_b = Q(np.sqrt(2 * gamma))          # QPSK P_b Q(sqrt(2*gamma))
    p = 1/ (snr) * np.exp(-gamma /(snr))
    return np.sum(P_b * p)

def qpsk_closed(snr):
    return 0.5 * (1 - np.sqrt(snr/(1 + snr)))


snr_db = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
snrs = 10**(snr_db/10)


plt.semilogy(snr_db, qpsk_closed(snrs), label='QPSK closed form')
plt.semilogy(snr_db, [qpsk_integrate(snr) for snr in snrs], label='QPSK integrate')
plt.xlabel('SNR (dB)')
plt.ylabel('Bit Error Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

